# JPA or Hibernate for Java Persistence?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm researching the development of Enterprise Applications in Java, .NET and Groovy. For each platform, we're going to try how hard it is to realize a simple SOAP web service. We'll use the tools and libraries that are most commonly used, to research the real world as accurately as possible.

In this regard, when using Hibernate for persistence, would it better reflect the real world to use the new JPA (Java Persistence API), or the Hibernate custom API that existed before JPA came around?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you're probably already aware, as of 3.2 Hibernate is JPA certified. You can easily use Hibernate as your JPA provider without having to use any of Hibernate's "custom" APIs.

I'd recommend using straight JPA with Hibernate as the provider. And use annotations rather than XML (much nicer).

Then when you need a little something extra you can always get the Hibernate Session. For example I often find I need to do this in order to pass a collection to a query as a parameter (setParameterList).

Comment: I know, but in a recent lecture we attended it was expressed that JPA is still immature and doesn't expose all the advanced features yet.

Comment: Keep in mind that JPA also has to act as a lowest common denominator between the underlying persistence layers it supports. So if Hibernate has whizzbang feature A and Toplink doesn't, then the JPA API can not expose the feature.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how you worded your question

> *new* JPA ... or *plain old* Hibernate

Sounds like one has been around forever and the other has just been released. Of course it's not true. JPA was influenced not just by Hibernate but also by TopLink and by J2EE entity beans. The first reference to JSR 220 draft is back from 2003 - how is that for new?
If you use JPA with Hibernate you still use Hibernate and is free to apply any proprietary extensions Hibernate has.

So the choice is yours: use proprietary API or use equivalent established and standard API...

Answer (score 0):

You could stick with a pure JPA spec, just in case you want to swap out Hibernate, but what you'll probably find at some point is that you're never going to swap it out, and you've been missing out on all the really great Hibernate-specific features.

I'd recommend using Hibernate directly, and as Damo suggests, annotations instead of XML. Make sure you have a firm understanding of the "magic" that Hibernate brings. If you're not careful, you could really thrash the database. For example, there's an n+1 query problem depending on how you do @OneToOne joins:

[Hibernate OneToOne automatic join fetching (resolving n+1 problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025583/hibernate-onetoone-automatic-join-fetching-resolving-n1-problem)

I'd also recommend to use an embedded database for unit/integration tests on your Hibernate queries, and watch the SQL that's generated to make sure it looks like something you'd write by hand.