# Hibernate OneToOne automatic join fetching (resolving n+1 problem)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

we have a n+1 select problem with Hibernate 3.3.

For simplicity's sake, I'll just do a short abstract example.

Suppose we have the following simple classes:

```
class MainEntity {
  @Id
  public Long id; //we have a table generator create this id

  @OneToOne ( mappedBy ="main" )
  public SubEntity subEntity;
}

class SubEntity {
 @Id
 @Column( name = "mainId" ) //note that this is the same column as the join column below
 public Long mainId; //in order to have the exact same id as the corresponding MainEntity

 @OneToOne ( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
 @JoinColumn ( name = "mainId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
 public MainEntity main; //this is used for navigation and queries (" ... subentity.main = :x")
}
```

So as you can see `SubEntity` has a relation to `MainEntity` that is expressed by two properties, where the `mainId` property is the one responsible for managing the relation/foreign key.

This works quite well and perfectly fits our needs.

However, there's one problem with eagerly loading the `SubEntity` along with the `MainEntity`.

Suppose I have a query that returns a collection of `MainEntity`. With the current setup, Hibernate will issue n + 1 selects: the query itself + n selects for each `SubEntity`.

Of course I could add a `join fetch` to the query, but I'd rather like Hibernate to do that automatically. Thus I tried adding `@Fetch( FetchMode.JOIN )`, but that didn't do anything.

I would also have no problem using `@Fetch( FetchMode.SUBSELECT )`, which should reduce the select statements to 2 - the original query and a select for the sub entities (at least that's what happens on another property annotated with `@CollectionOfElements` and `@Fetch( FetchMode.SUBSELECT )`).



So the question is: how would I tell Hibernate to *automatically* join fetch or use a single select in order to eagerly load the sub entities? Am I missing something?


Thanks in advance,

Thomas

PS: One thing that might be a problem might be the `mappedBy = "main"` which doesn't reference the actual id column, but I can't change it to `mappedBy = "id"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to shared primary keys between MainEntity and SubEntity use `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `MapsId` annotation.

By using `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` the entity is loaded
 by joining the `MainEntity` table with the `SubEntity` table using the same primary key. It should resolve the n+1 problems.

The `MapsId` annotation ask Hibernate to copy the identifier from
another associated entity in our example will copy the `SubEntity.mainEntity.id` to `SubEntity.id`.

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "main_Id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private SubEntity  subEntity ;
}


@Entity
public class SubEntity 
{
    @Id @Column(name="main_Id_FK") Long id;

    @MapsId 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_Id_FK")    
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private MainEntity mainEntity;        

}
```

Hibernate Reference Documentation:

[PrimaryKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)
  [MapsId](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `@MapsId`, thanks for that. I'll try it out. Even in the case the n+1 problem would not be solved, I'd still prefer that approach to our current one. Just a question: would that allow me to actually just set the id without having a reference to `MainEntity`? We have cases where missing `SubEntity` instances are created and we only have the id of the corresponding `MainEntity`. If possible, I'd like to rather not have to load `MainEntity` for just setting the reference. In other words: what would happen if `id` had a value and `mainEntity`was `null`?

Comment: I just had a look at the `@MapsId` documentation you linked, and unfortunately it seems that this annotation was introduced with Hibernate 3.5 (and thus JPA 2). However, we're currently stuck with JBoss 4.2.3 (which doesn't support JPA 2) and thus can't use Hibernate 3.5 (we're working on migration to JBoss 6, but that'll take a while).

Comment: @Thomas To Answer your first comment. How to create a `SubEntity` with only the Id of the `MainEntity`. You need to use the `EntityManager.getReference` to get a reference to `MainEntity` without loading it and set it to the `SubEntiy.main` relation without loading the Main.

Comment: Without `@MapsID` you will have to manually assign the `SubEntity.id` before saving it and set the `SubEntity.main` relation `insertable = false,updatable =false,nullable = false` like in your example. You can continue to use the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn@ on `MainEntity.subEntity` this should correct the select problems.

Comment: yes, I forgot about `EntityManager.getReference(...)` - thanks for reminding me. If I understand you correctly, I'd just have to use `@PrimaryKeyColumn` and leave the rest of the code unchanged, right? I'll try that and post the results.

Comment: I tested now, but without real success. I still get the n+1 selects when using queries without fetch join. Adding `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` didn't work as didn't adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` to either `SubEntity.main` or `SubEntity.id`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options to avoid the questions n +1:

```
 Lot size

 subselect

 Make a LEFT JOIN in the query
```

[Here FAQ1](https://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A23)
[Here FAQ2](https://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A30)

Comment: Both links lead me to the same page, any more specific links? Additionally: `Lot Size`: I guess you mean `Batch size` - doesn't work here, `subselect` - I tried that but as already mentioned, it didn't work, `left join` - I'd rather do a fetch join, but as stated, I'd like to not have to add it to each query.